# Getting the keyboard cursor location/coordinates in all applications

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, caret

Right now I'm using the functions `GetCaretPos()` and `GetGUIThreadInfo()` to get the current keyboard cursor/caret coordinates. These work properly in applications like Notepad and Wordpad and return the correct coordinates, but in applications such as Firefox, Thunderbird, and others, the coordinates returned are always 0, 0, no matter where the keyboard cursor is.

I know it's not impossible to get the keyboard cursor/caret coordinates in these applications because when I use the [Yahoo KeyKey](http://tw.media.yahoo.com/keykey/) IME in them, it pops-up a dialog right where the keyboard cursor is positioned.

Problem is, since KeyKey is not open source, I have no idea how it's doing it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or knows the correct function(s) to use it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Browsers don't use Windows controls, they cook their own windowless versions of them.  Yes, I would expect Yahoo to go the 100 miles it takes to support a browser.  Good luck digging through the Firefox API.  And all the rest of them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So in other words, there is no solution other than GetCaretPos() or GetGUIThreadInfo() *unless* I want to spend a lot of time figuring out each individual app's API? There's not some other Windows function that might work for at least some of the other apps that the first two functions don't work for? I noticed that KeyKey also works in apps like Safari, Opera, Chrome, Songbird, and a lot of other apps that the first two functions don't work for. Seems crazy that Yahoo would take the time to support all of those individual apps.